# What does it mean that a diagram is commutative in category theory?

Tags: category-theory

'In category theory, a diagram commutes means that between any two objects in the diagram, there is a unique morphism. And the identity morphisms and compositions of morphisms might be omitted in the diagram.'

I can understand the first half of this paragraph. However, the meaning of the last half is vague. My question is very explicit, as follows:

If there is one object, which appears in the diagram twice, is there an implicit identity morphism between its twice appearance? And does it mean that all the compositions of morphisms from object $X$ to object $X$ is the identity morphism of $X$?

Comment: "a diagram commutes means that between any two objects in the diagram, there is a unique morphism." -- To my understanding, this isn't even part of the standard definition of a (commutative) diagram. To answer your second question, at least in my experience we rarely have the same object twice in a diagram. Even so, it will usually be obvious from context whether we want to display the identity morphism.

Comment: These feel like ideas moreso for how to display commutative diagrams, than hard rules and definitions that a diagram must have "this", after all. Commutative diagrams generally just mean "if you have $X$ as a start point and $Y$ as the end point, every composition of arrows that takes you from $X$ to $Y$ (no matter how meandering) are equal."

Comment: @EeveeTrainer Thanks! I know my description is informal because I am just a beginner. However, you didn't give me an answer to my question because we have such an assignment and I'm still not sure if it is commutative or not :(

Comment: I guess the first sentence has to be understood as "any choice of path between two given objects yields the same morphism, so in the end there is only one morphism". It does not necessarily mean that there is physically one arrow drawn.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general I would assume that a diagram said to commute and containing
the same object twice does not have an implicit identity between those appearances of the same object.

You do get the same object twice in examples such as those shown in:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monad_(category_theory)
with the diagrams defining a monad. In one diagram $T^2$ appears twice with no identity being intended. In the other both $T^2$ and $T$ appear twice with an explicit identity on $T$ but definitely no intention that there is one on $T^2$.

Comment: Oh thanks! That is a concrete evidence!:)